# File parsing in bash

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I have a text file with below content:

```
Hostname=Hostname2,Hostname3
```

using bash commands how can I fetch only `Hostname2` and `Hostname3` into a separate file. I want `Hostname2` and `Hostname3` to be in different lines. 
Sometimes the text file will be like more than 2 hosts,
`Hostname=Hostname2,Hostname3,Hostname4`
then i'll have to fetch all 3 hosts into the separate file. How can this be done in bash?

Comment: have you tried using sed to split at the equals then split at the commas?

Comment: please share your efforts !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
egrep -o '[^=,]+' /path/to/file | tail -n +2 > /path/to/new\ file
```

#### Explanation

**`egrep`:** A file pattern searcher that allows you to search the contents of files and match lines using regular expressions.

**`-o`:** An option for `egrep` that instructs it to only print the matching parts of the line, instead of the entire line.

**`'[^=,]+'`:** The regular expression used to match the contents of the file.  Here, `[^=,]+` denotes any character that isn't `=` or `,` occurring at least once in succession.  Simply put, it matches words separated by either `=` or `,`.

The result of the `egrep` command is:

```
Hostname
Hostname2
Hostname3
Hostname4
```

**`|`:** Pipe the results of the previous command (`egrep`) into the next command:

**`tail -n +2`:** Takes the input and starts at line `+2` relative to the beginning (i.e. the second line), and prints the remaining lines.

Taking the previous command's output as its input, the result of `tail` is:

```
Hostname2
Hostname3
Hostname4
```

**`>`:** Finally, this redirects the output of the previous command and writes it to the specified file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk to print the second "field" of the (only) line, instructing it to use `=` as the the "field separator" with the `-F` option. `awk`'s output is "Hostname2,Hostname3".

The `tr` ("translate") utility can then be used to change all commas to newlines. The result is printed to standard out so that your shell can redirect it to a file via `>`.

```
awk -F= '{print $2}' file | tr ',' '\n' > hostnames.txt
```

Comment: You could use `cut -d= -f2` instead of that awk, or alternatively do the substitution in awk `gsub(/,/, "\n", $2)` before printing instead of piping to `tr`.